# I bought it at, I bought it on, I bought it from

Tags: grammar

Someone was asking:

`Do we order things "off" a website or "on" a website?`

I suggest it's `from` as it's a specific place (if virtual.)

What is correct here. Cannot for the life of me find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are various options, and they each are based on a different metaphor for websites.

Is a website like a person, perhaps in a market, selling you something?
*"I bought it **from** Amazon"* or, the more colloquial *"I bought it **off** Amazon"*.

Is a website like a shop, which you go into in order to buy something?
*"I bought it **in** Amazon"*

Is a website a collection of words and pictures which you view **on** your computer's monitor, like words and pictures which might be **on** the page of a book?
*"I bought it **on** Amazon"*

Of these metaphors, the latter is the most common, and we do talk about being "on" websites, generally.

Comment: I am surfing :-)